# Convert Dataset into String in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am having an error with compiling the codes. It says that dataset cant be converted to string.. Please help me.. I have done this by using SQL Stored procedure.. I have to get the employee name saved in master table to retrieve the ID and then ID should retrieve the leave details from leave details table.

```
 Public Shared Function GetEmpID(ByVal EmpName As String) As DataSet
    Dim db As Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(HttpContext.Current.Session("CompanyID").ToString) ' TO Get Database Connection
    Dim dbCommand As DbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("spRetrieveEmpID") ' Stored Procedure to Execute
    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "EmployeeName", DbType.String, EmpName) ' Parameter for Stored Procedure
    Return db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand) ' Execute Stored Procedure
End Function

Public Shared Function EmpLeaveDetails(ByVal EmployeeID As String) As DataSet
    Dim db As Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(HttpContext.Current.Session("CompanyID").ToString) ' TO Get Database Connection
    Dim dbCommand As DbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("spHRLeaveEntitlement") ' Stored Procedure to Execute
    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "EmployeeID", DbType.String, EmployeeID) ' Parameter for Stored Procedure
    Return db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand) ' Execute Stored Procedure
End Function
```

And this is my leave.aspx.vb codes

```
 Private Sub ddlEmpName_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs) Handles ddlEmpName.SelectedIndexChanged

    EmployeeID = TESTING.GetEmpID(ddlEmpName.Text)

    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        dgLeaveDetails.DataSource = ds
        dgLeaveDetails.DataBind()
    End If

    ds1 = TESTING.EmpLeaveDetails(EmployeeID)
    dgLeaveDetails.DataSource = ds1

    ddlEmpName.SelectedIndex = -1
    dgLeaveDetails.Rebind()

End Sub
```

Comment: can you include de error message?

Comment: @emecas: Thanks for your initiative.. The error has been solved.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
EmployeeID = TESTING.GetEmpID(ddlEmpName.Text)
```

looks like the problem to me.

You should use:

```
Dim dst As Dataset = TESTING.GetEmpID(ddlEmpName.Text)
EmployeeID = CStr(dst.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("EmployeeID"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `EmployeeID`, like this:

```
EmployeeID = TESTING.GetEmpID(ddlEmpName.Text)
```

The `GetEmpID` method returns a `DataSet` object.  Therefore, `EmployeeID` references a `DataSet`, rather than equaling a single ID value.  Later, you try to pass `EmployeeID` to the `EmpLeaveDetails` method like this:

```
ds1 = TESTING.EmpLeaveDetails(EmployeeID)
```

However, the `EmpLeaveDetails` method takes a `String` as a parameter.  Therefore, you are trying to pass a `DataSet` into a method that expects a `String`.  Since `DataSet` objects cannot be automatically converted to the `String` type, the compiler gives the error.

To fix it, you need to either have the `GetEmpID` return a string, or else you need to retrieve the single string value from the `DataSet` before passing it to the `EmpLeaveDetails` method.